# XMLHttpRequest bad behaviour loading XML files

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

Last year I discovered that XMLHttpRequest was misbehaving on some files on some browsers. Notably it didn't like reading some (but not all) xml files in the root of a site. I finally got the time to see if I could come up with something that worked across browsers.

My solution is to place the xml files in a subdirectory. Seems obvious but there are some quirks I came across while trying this. Here's some code to demonstrate what I am talking about:

```
function importXML(fileName) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      var xmlhttp = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
      var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.addEventListener("load", loadListener);
    xmlhttp.addEventListener("error", errorListener);

    xmlhttp.open("GET", fileName);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Assume I have the file xmlfile.xml on the site's root and also in an xml folder:

Simply using xmlfile.xml on the site may or may not work. Different files seem to load on different browsers.

If is send the fileName as something like "xml/xmlfile.xml", it will load on all of the browser's I've tried it on.

If I use "file:///" in front of the file name, the file will fail to load no matter where it is.

If I use this outside of a web server (e.g. simply open an html page from a local directory) it doesn't work on some files at the root and on any files in the xml folder.

Since multiple browsers exhibit similar characteristics, I have to assume this is a deliberate decision to have the browser behave this way. However I can't think of a good reason why, for example, xmlfile.xml is disallowed but xml/xmlfile.xml is OK. Even stranger is the question of why file:///xml/xmlfile.xml fails.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: file is working off your computer.... Are you not running this off of a server?

Comment: Well the reason you can't use `file:///` is because you're accessing a remote file using HTTP, not a file in local filestore.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought file:/// was relative to the page.

Anyone have any explanation for the weird behaviour of requests from the site root?